# How to change a HEAP/MEMORY MySQL table's indexes from HASH to BTREE?

Tags: mysql, indexing, b-tree

I have a MySQL table with the HEAP/MEMORY storage type that was converted from MyISAM.  The indexes were automatically converted to HASH, but I need them to be BTREE.  How do I change them from HASH to BTREE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dropping the indexes does work, but this wouldn't work with the PRIMARY KEY without doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the indexes and recreate them `using btree` ... they don't contain real data so you lose nothing, and in a heap/memory table it should be a pretty fast operation.

Comment: I can't drop the PRIMARY key.

Comment: @James why can't you drop the primary key? `ALTER TABLE your_table DROP PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key